# Can't get text from textbox inside a listview

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, binding, textbox

XAML code:

```
<ListView.View>
    <GridView x:Name="myGridView">
        <GridViewColumn Width="0" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Id}">
            <GridViewColumnHeader Content="Id" IsHitTestVisible="False" />
        </GridViewColumn>
        <GridViewColumn Width="50" Header="Cant">
            <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBox FontSize="11" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
        </GridViewColumn>
        <GridViewColumn Width="300" Header="Nombre" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Nombre}" />
    </GridView>
</ListView.View>
```

C# code to fill myListView with items from another listview:

```
private void myListView_Drop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Data.GetDataPresent("myFormat"))
    {
        foreach (var item in e.Data.GetData("myFormat") as Dictionary<string, string>)
        {
            var itemC = new {Id = item.Key, Cant = "", Nombre = item.Value};
            myListView.Items.Add(itemC);
            myListView.SelectedItem = itemC;
        }
    }
}
```

C# code to retrieve items from myListView:

```
private Dictionary<string, string> GenerateArts()
{
    var arts = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    dynamic result = myListView.Items;

    foreach (var item in result)
       arts.Add((string) item.Id, (string) item.Cant);

    return arts;
}
```

After myListView is filled users can write numbers in each textbox of the column 'Cant' but later, when a button is clicked and GenerateArts() is invoked, those numbers are lost, i.e., item.Cant is "" (empty string) for each item.

What's the problem?

Edit:

When GenerateArts() is invoked the values for item.Id and item.Nombre are there as expected. The problem is with item.Cant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bind `Cant` to `TextBox.Text` property as shown below.

XAML:

```
            <GridViewColumn Width="50" Header="Cant">
                <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBox FontSize="11" Text="{Binding Cant}" MinWidth="30"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
            </GridViewColumn>
```

Code behind change:

```
var itemC = new MyData() { Id = item.Key, Cant = "", Nombre = item.Value };
```

MyData class

```
public class MyData
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Cant { get; set; }
    public string Nombre { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Anand. I tried that before but when items from the other listview are dropped on myListView I get (a lot of times) this exception: A TwoWay or OneWayToSource binding cannot work on the read-only property 'Cant' of type '<>f_AnonymousType2'3[System.String,System.String,System.String]'. Even if I drag and drop only an item.

Comment: Was running your code and I got the exception too. Instead of creating an anonymous class with properties,  can't you define the class itself?

Comment: Yes, I can. I'll try that.

Comment: Perfect! Thanks a lot. :) I can't upvote cause of my reputation (this's my first question.)

Answer (score -1):

Are you using if(!IsPostBack) on the page_load event? maybe you're binding the data again?

Comment: Thanks Marciano. I don't know what IsPostBack is but I will research right now.

Comment: Marciano: this isn't a web application, it's a desktop one.